# Logging request and response information in an Azure function without code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I feel like there should be a way to do it using Application Insights, but I haven't found a way. If I were to do it in code I would have to do it for each function. As the title implies I am interested in knowing the request and response for each API call in a function.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ready to use mechanism. Even if you're using Application Insights, you'll need to specify the log level + what you want to log (the request / response content). It's not enabled by default as it implies cost associated with the storage of the logs (Log Analytics).

Comment: I also forgot to mention it's not enabled by default as you can 'log' personal / private information that a person with permission to see the logs should not see. (GDPR / PII / ETC ). So definitely, you should be responsible to specify what you want/need to log and when.